# How to use npm's readline-Sync input masking function in MS Bot Dialog(NodeJS)?

Tags: node.js, npm, botframework, chatbot

I want user to enter a password on my MS Bot, the input need to be masked during password entry, there is no hyperlinnk or any card used. I found readline-Sync in "npm" which can hide an input. How to use the readline-sync in an MS Bot Waterfall Dialog?

Comment: You cannot, that feature would have to provided & supported by the channels. And as of now no channel support entering password in bot (although I could be wrong). What you can do is provide a url to login page by bot. Ask user to login, when login successfully, ask them to continue using bot.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, masking user inputs is not a supported feature at this time. Please refer to [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2788) for other possible solutions.

As botbuilder v4 is currently in preview and will be the primary focus going forward, I would suggest submitting a feature request against this version for future inplementation. You can do so on the v4 repo located [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues).